# Where can I acquire a specific copy of Let's Go!! Love Summer?

Tags: cute-high-earth-defense-club-love

I am the curator of an exhibition on Easter Island in popular culture (http://www.moaiculture.com) and I am trying to track down a few missing items. If you can assist we will acknowledge you in the exhibition. There is a specific issue of 'Let's Go!! Love Summer', which appears to be out of print. Does anywhere know where I can read a copy online or purchase from a seller. Best - Ian

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the cover of [a fanbook](https://booth.pm/ja/items/350884) for *Cute High Earth Defense Club LOVE!*, an anime and light novel series. The back cover specifically names the *Cute High Earth Defense Club LOVE! LOVE!* sequel to the original anime, so content may be specific to that part of the series. (As I am unfamiliar with the series and also no access to the actual pages, I do not know for sure.) The title "Let's Go!! Love Summer" is a reference to [a character song](https://binan-koukou-chikyuu-bouei-bu-love.fandom.com/wiki/Let%27s_Go!!_LOVE_Summer%E2%99%AA) in the anime.

Unfortunately, the fanbook appears to be out of stock, judging from a [Google Translate copy](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fbooth.pm%2Fja%2Fitems%2F350884) of the webpage. It is possible that someone might resell it somewhere, but I am not an expert on where to locate such sales.